# Problems installing python module pybfd

Tags: python, pip, easy-install

I've been trying to install the `pybfd` module but nothing works so far.

Tried the following:

`pip install pybfd` returns `error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized`. After a quick search I found the `--egg` option for `pip` which seems to work, says successfully installed but when I try to run my code `ImportError: No module named pybfd.bfd`

`easy_install pybfd` returns an error as well: 
`Writing /tmp/easy_install-oZUgBf/pybfd-0.1.1/setup.cfg
Running pybfd-0.1.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-oZUgBf/pybfd-0.1.1/egg-dist-tmp-gWwhoT
[-] Error : unable to determine correct include path for bfd.h / dis-asm.h
No eggs found in /tmp/easy_install-oZUgBf/pybfd-0.1.1/egg-dist-tmp-gWwhoT (setup script problem?)`

For the last attempt I downloaded the `pybfd` repo from GitHub and ran the setup script: `[-] Error : unable to determine correct include path for bfd.h / dis-asm.h`

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing all this and how to actually install the module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error I discovered that `binutils-dev` and `python-dev` packages were missing and causing the header path errors. After installing those the setup script worked.